# Show start and stop date and time of a machine cycle

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that goes like this (pec_za_starenje_prva_start_stop):

| ID | TimeLogged | Tag1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-25 21:56:19 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-10-26 04:13:24 | 0 |
| 3 | 2022-10-26 05:42:54 | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-10-26 12:18:27 | 0 |
| 5 | 2022-10-26 14:29:36 | 1 |
| 6 | 2022-10-26 21:22:21 | 0 |

```
id              | int   
TimeLogged      | DateTime   
Tag1            | int
```

Number 1 from "Tag1" should signal that the cycle has started, and 0 should signal that the cycle has finished. So, I would need the table that would look like this:

| ID | start_cycle | end_cycle | total_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-25 21:56:19 | 2022-10-26 04:13:24 | 377minutes |
| 2 | 2022-10-26 05:42:54 | 2022-10-26 12:18:27 | 395minutes |
| 3 | 2022-10-26 14:29:36 | 2022-10-26 21:22:21 | 1132minutes |

It doesn't matter in which format the total time will be, this is just an example.

This is the closest thing that I found but it's not working properly, as it shows only the start time:

```sql
SELECT ID,  
       TimeLogged start_cycle,  
       next_TimeLogged end_cycle,  
       TIMEDIFF(next_TimeLogged, TimeLogged) total_time  
FROM (  
  SELECT *, LEAD(TimeLogged) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TimeLogged)  
 next_TimeLogged  
  FROM pec_za_starenje_prva_start_stop  
) t  
WHERE Tag1 = '1'  
ORDER BY start_cycle;
```

Comment: `1132minutes` is wrong result - the difference is ~7 hours = 420 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH
cte AS (
  SELECT TimeLogged TimeLoggedIn, 
         LEAD(TimeLogged) OVER win TimeLoggedOut,
         Tag1,
         LEAD(Tag1) OVER win tag2
  FROM pec_za_starenje_prva_start_stop
  WINDOW win AS (ORDER BY TimeLogged)
  )
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TimeLoggedIn) ID,
       TimeLoggedIn start_cycle,
       TimeLoggedOut end_cycle,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TimeLoggedIn, TimeLoggedOut) total_time
FROM cte
WHERE Tag1 AND !Tag2;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/NVW9YGb0